Comparing Gaussian 16 and ORCA 5.0.3 single point energy calculations
I'm performing single-point energy (SPE) calculations on a diatomic molecule using M06-2X functional with cc-pV5Z basis set. All other features are being used default.
The problem is that when I'm using Gaussian 16 for this SPE calculation, it leads to a different value in comparison to ORCA 5.0.3 for the same geometry, functional and basis set.
I'm attaching the input files for both the software. Could someone please help with what change I should make in ORCA input to match the results with that of Gaussian 16?
Input for ORCA
! M062X cc-pV5Z 

* int 0 1

X 0 0 0 0 0 0

X 1 0 0 2.701319 0 0

*

Input for Gaussian 16
#n M062X/cc-pV5Z SP

Dimer SPE


0 1

X 

X  1 B1

Variables:

B1        2.701319


I also tried removing the default RI approximation for DFT calculations in ORCA, but the results are still very different: the difference is at the 3rd decimal place in Hartree units, which is somewhere around $\pu{100 cm^-1}.$

Hi, the actual implementation of DFT grids varies in quantum chemistry software packages. It is unlikely to obtain identical energies (e.g. <1e-6 a.u. difference) using DFT methods due to different implementations. But you can use the wave function method, e.g. the simplest Hartree-Fock (HF) method. HF energy difference among different packages can be smaller than 1e-8 a.u. if proper keywords are specified. There is no DFT grid problem in HF. So, just try HF.

The description on the Gaussian website suggests they might use a slightly modified version of the cc-pvNz basis sets. You might try running both calculations with the basis explicitly written out in the input. You can get the basis in the appropriate format for each program from the Basis Set Exchange

@jxzou Thank you for your valuable comment. I do not intend to get an energy difference of 1e-6; a 1e-5 will work perfectly fine for me, but to my surprise, the results don't even have a difference of 1e-4; the difference is coming out of an order of 1e-3. I cannot use HF for my problem, but thanks for the suggestion.

@Tyberius, Thank you so much for your valuable comment. I looked at each coefficient of the basis set for my atom of interest for both Gaussian and ORCA, but each coefficient in the basis set for Gaussian matches with the corresponding coefficient in the basis set for ORCA.

My first thought: Is Gaussian still using Cartesian basis set (CAO), i.e. 6d, 10f, etc.  by default while ORCA uses spherical AOs 5d, 7f, ... ?
Second idea: That's a small, linear and thus highly symmetric molecule. Total energy might depend on the start orbital guess and the occupation. Did you check that you got the identical electronic state (if you have turned on symmetry)?
Third point: For comparisons I'd avoid M06-2X and try PBE0 or PBE. Just to check if the difference stems from functional evaluation.

@Uwe, Thank you for your input. I tried turning on symmetry in ORCA, but the energy remains unchanged. I have tried using other functions, such as B3LYP and mPW2PLYP, but the difference has further increased. I'm getting an energy difference of about 1.4eV in the case of B3LYP and a stunning 16eV in the case of mPW2PLYP (these are for the N2 molecule at the given distance).

Just to add one more thing, I initially was having energy differences in the case of Ab-initio methods too, like MP2, CCSD, etc., but that was due to default FrozenCore Approximation in Gaussian16.

Switch off RI in ORCA by adding NORI to the ! input line (and then you also do not need auxiliary basis functions def2/J). And use B3LYP/G as DFT functional, as this is the flavour of B3-LYP that Gaussian uses (VWN3 vs VNW5 correlation).

@Uwe, Thank you so much for your comment. I wasn't really aware of this distinction between B3LYP functional in Gaussian and ORCA. As per your suggestion, using B3LYP/G really produced nearly the same results. Now, I really doubt if this distinction in functionals also exists for other functionals, like mPW2PLYP and DSD-BLYP, as results for mPW2PLYP are still very far off, about 60eV difference in energy is produced for N2 molecule at a bond length of 2.701319 A when switching from Gaussian to ORCA (NO RI was used).

mPW2PLYP, DSD-BLYP are double hybrids. If you get  larger deviation there you have to check if Gaussian and ORCA do the MP2 part identically. First difference might be traditional MP2 (the 'good old original but very slow' MP2) and RI-MP2. Another typical trap are frozen cores. Gaussian by default freezes core orbitals in MP2 while other packages do only upon user request. I do not know what ORCA does, but I think it also freezes by default?

@MeliodusSama please ask a new question on the main page rather than asking further questions in comments.

According to the discussions in comments above, you do not want to (or you cannot) use the HF method, but accept the DFT energy difference between Gaussian/ORCA being around 1e-5 a.u. This is not difficult to be achieved.
Since I do not know what is your X element, or whether the chemical bond is stretched from its equilibrium bond length, I'll take the N2 and Br2 diatomic molecules as examples. Here is the Gaussian input file of N2
%mem=180GB
%nprocshared=64
%chk=N2_M062X.chk
#p M062X/cc-pV5Z nosymm int=nobasistransform

title

0 1
N   0.0   0.0   0.0
N   0.0   0.0   1.092


After the Gaussian job is accomplished, run the following commands
formchk N2_M062X.chk N2_M062X.fch
fch2mkl N2_M062X.fch -dft M062X
orca_2mkl N2_M062X_o -gbw

One obtains the ORCA files N2_M062X_o.inp and N2_M062X_o.gbw. Then modify keywords to turn off the RI approximation and use very tight SCF threshold
! RKS M062X noRI VeryTightSCF defgrid3

Note that do not delete keywords
%scf
 Thresh 1e-12
 Tcut 1e-14
end

which is already written in this input file. This makes ORCA generate more accurate integrals than default. Now submit the ORCA job and it will be accomplished soon. Similar computations can be performed for Br2. Results are collected as follows



Mol.
Gaussian
ORCA
Abs(diff)




N2
-109.542274280
-109.542291782509
1.75e-5


Br2
-5148.48560989
-5148.485690526614
8.06e-5



Gaussian 16 and ORCA 5.0.4 are used here. I assume that these energy differences meet your requirements.
Some addition comments:
(1) The fch2mkl utility is used above to transfer MOs and basis set from Gaussian to ORCA. This has three advantages: (i) ensure that two programs use exactly the same basis set data; (ii) ensure that the SCF in two programs are converged into the same solution (since there are multiple SCF solutions for transition-metal diatomic molecules and stretched molecules); (iii) save the SCF computational time in ORCA.
(2) Gaussian uses spherical harmonic functions for cc-pVnZ by default, so this is not the problem.
(3) If you use ORCA 6, the energy difference would be decreased slightly due to better DFT grid implementation, if you care about the energy difference very much.
(4) I want to repeat some words I said in comments above: the actual implementation of DFT grids varies in quantum chemistry software packages, one can hardly obtain extremely close energies. This is not something which one can control via writing some fancy keywords, but already determined (i.e. hard-coded) by program developers. If you want even closer energies, it is recommended to use another type of method, e.g. HF.
Hope this answer solves your problem. Any suggestions, comments or further discussions are welcomed.

Hi, to summarize: using the same orbitals and no symmetry does give the same answer. That's not really unexpected as both tools do more or less essentially the same task (as all other GTO based molecular DFT codes I hope).  The interesting next step, and to answer the initial question, would be to run ORCA without fch2mkl.
My personal experience is that small symmetric molecules are often more tough to treat correctly than larger non-symmetric system...

When increasing the grid sizes, one would expect the difference to shrink. Also, it is possible to use HF orbitals (which are first shown to match between the programs) as input for a single DFT SCF step to avoid error accumulation via the SCF procedure.

@jxzou Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I repeated the calculation for the N2 molecule at the distance of 1.092 A using your Gaussian File and followed all the procedures in a stepwise manner (including installing MOKIT) and fortunately got the exact same results as were given by you in the answer with the same energy difference of 1.75e-5. But.... the moment I change the functional from M062X to B3LYP, I'm again stuck with the same problem of extraordinary difference in energy values, and this time, the energy produced by Gaussian and ORCA differ by 1e-2.

I want to repeat that I'm using everything the same as mentioned in the Gaussian input by you, the same basis set cc-pV5Z, and the same set of keywords, except the functional. I'm also attaching the link to the input and output files from both Gaussian16 and ORCA: files

please let me know if these are not accessible at:- samameliodus@gmail.com

@MeliodusSama please see this and replace the Google Drive link accordingly: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5.

Sorry for the late reply @MeliodusSama , I went for a conference last week. It is probably because you should run something like fch2mkl N2_B3LYP.fch -dft "B3LYP/G" since B3LYP/G in ORCA is that B3LYP in Gaussian.

Thanks, It is sorted now @jxzou
